# how to import a component from a file that has several components

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, frontend

I want to import a specific Vue component from a file that has several vue components into another component file

I have tried the normal import component from './components/SeveralComponents but that didn't work

```
Vue.component('firstComponent', {
    props: [a,b,c],
    template: <p>hello world</p>
});

Vue.component('secondComponent', {
    props: [c,d,e],
    template: <h1> heading1 </h1>
});

<div>
    <secondComponent></secondComponent>
</div>

export default {
    name: 'SeveralComponents',
    data() {
},
    methods: {
        method1() {
}
```

How do i import firstComponent into another component file?

I expect just the firstComponent

Comment: You need to `export` your components in the js file to be able to `import` them elsewhere.

Comment: You have two global component registrations, so you don't need to export/import them, as they're globally available. If you actually meant them to be locally registered, you should export the component definitions (e.g., by name) so that they could be imported into another file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can export the options object using a named export, and register the object with Vue in another step.

Then import the named export in your client file.

```js
export const firstComponent = {
    props: [a,b,c],
    template: <p>hello world</p>
}
Vue.component('firstComponent', firstComponent); 


import {firstComponent} from 'MultiComponent.vue'
```